# Is it possible to temporarily destroy a php session?

Tags: php, session

I'm using php `session_start` to store temporary variables along user navigation.
I have some script that takes several seconds to process so if the user wants to open another page in another browser tab during this time, he can't because `session_start` will lock execution.
Then I call `session_destroy` before long processes, but that deletes the temporary variables that I still need.
Is my only choice to use cookies ?
Isn't there a `session_end` equivalent ?

Comment: Show that script. Also, opening another page which is supposed to be handled by another script should not hinder with this script at all. Or is your server is too busy executing that long script?

Comment: how many variable you are setting temporary ? may be you can do it by grouping.

Comment: If you do a session_start at the beginning of all your script and have a script take a long time you won't be able to open another page until it finish. I always worked like that for me in php. For that script I only use two variables in session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try session_abort instead of using session_destroy:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-abort.php

Comment: Yes this is it ! Thanks

Comment: This won't save any session variable changes. `session_write_close()` might be more appropriate.